# Where are my downloaded NuGet package stored in my project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite, razor-pages, nuget-package

Beginner question.
I´m playing around and coding a .Net 6, Web App, ASP.Net, Razor pages.

I download some NuGet packages, but i cant find them in my project folder.
C:\Users{User}\source\repos\Prodject

Where are they saved?

Googling where it is saved in my project

Comment: They are no longer saved in the individual project folder. There's now a global location, which helps avoid extra processing when you have multiple projects that use the same nuget packages.

Comment: But how can my Pridject use the downloaded NyGet Librarys if they are not inclouded in my pridject?